# How to inner join of array type in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

employees table with columns:
id (pk) BIGINT, name TEXT, email TEXT, work_locations BIGINT[].

work_locations columns contains the location table ids.

location table with columns:
id (pk) BIGINT, lat DECIMAL(12,9), long DECIMAL(12,9).

I want a result like

```
id  name  email            lat,      long   
1   name  email@email.com  23.345   54.3678
```

I am not able to join two table on work_locations and ids.
How to join these two tables?

Comment: What if an employee has more than one work location? What output do you expect then? One row for each location?

Comment: yes, a new row for each location.

Comment: It is very bad design to store references to data in an array. The query will be inefficient. You should normalize the table.

Answer (score 2):

You can join using the `ANY` operator:

```
select e.*, 
       l.lat, 
       l.long
from employees e
  join locations l on l.id = any(e.work_locations)
order by e.id;
```

---

In general I would recommend to **not** store foreign keys in arrays like that. You should think about a properly normalized model with a many-to-many link table between `employees` and `locations`

Answer (score 0):

You can `unnest()`:

```
select e.*, l.*
from employees e cross join lateral
     unnest(work_locations) wl(work_location) left join
     locations l
     on wl.work_location = l.id;
```